# SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where user id='1'' at line 3

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to update my database i search for so many codes is still not working

```
 if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
 $id = $_GET['did'];
 $sname = $_GET['sname'];
 $oname = $_GET['oname'];
 $sex = $_GET['sex'];
 $freceipt = $_GET['freceipt'];
 $j_regno = $_GET['j_regno'];
 $department = $_GET['department'];
 $rs =  "update user set
surname='$sname', othername='$oname', sex='$sex',
fee_receipt='$freceipt', j_regno='$j_regno', department='$department', where `id`=`$id`";
$query =mysqli_query($cn,$rs) or die(mysqli_error($cn));
}
```

The error displaying is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where `id`=`1`' at line 3"

Comment: there's a white space in your "where user id-'1'", remove the white space

Comment: your user id might be a integer. But here you are formatting the query considering it as string

Comment: @Dinidu it doesn't matter you can use ' ' with any data type of Database as it converts this internally.

Comment: try `department='$department'` sometimes it shows error due to some mistakes in previous section

Comment: You need to update your `department=$department` into `department='$department'` as it seems you were passing string instead within `department` field

Comment: There's an errant comma, I think

Comment: i have updated it, is still showing an error

Comment: @strawberry you right...... thanks all

Comment: @OnahOnallySunday Looking at your edit history, it seems that the errant comma (as pointed out by @Strawberry) was only added in edit #4 (you're having more errors per edit). In the same edit, you also added backticks to `$id` - this is an invalid syntax, you need to be using single quotes for values.

Answer (score 1):

As your `user id` column contains a space, you need to wrap the column name with backticks i.e.

```
WHERE `user id` = '$id'
```

From the MySQL docs, [Section 9.2 Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html), it is noted that (emphasis mine):

> An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains **special characters** or is a reserved word, you *must* quote it whenever you refer to it. (Exception: A reserved word that follows a period in a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted.)

And from the same section:

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”).

Whitespaces can be considered special characters in this context.

Identifiers usually refer to the tables, views and column names. If you ever have any tables or views with whitespaces or special characters in the name, you can use backticks to escape them as well.

---

**Edit**

The answer above is for your original question. In edit 4, you used backticks for the following part of your query:

```
WHERE `id` = `$id`
```

...which is syntactically incorrect. MySQL treats `$id` as a database identifier in this case, instead of a value. Instead, it should be wrapped in single quotes:

```
WHERE `id` = '$id'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` clause column have a space and so needs escaping using backtique operator like

```
where `user id` = '$id'
```

(OR)

```
where "user id" = '$id'
```

After your edit, you are still getting that error cause you haven't quoted the value for `Department` field. It should be as below [as correctly pointed by @Uchina]

```
department = '$department'
```

Your query statement should look like

```
$rs =  "update user set
surname='$sname', othername='$oname', sex='$sex',
fee_receipt='$freceipt', j_regno='$j_regno', department='$department' where id='$id'";
```

Comment: i have edited the question, user is the table name. i have try to use the double quote `where "id" = $id`

Comment: @OnahOnallySunday Your error states that it's near `'where user id='1'' at line 3`, but your query has the relevant `user` part removed. The error and your code does not match anymore. So are you still getting the exact same error?

Comment: OP is trying to implement string within `department=$department` instead of  `department='$department'`

Comment: thanks all this the error message is now showing You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where `id`=`1`' at line 3

Comment: @OnahOnallySunday, just edited my answer. Check edited answer again.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma after `department='$department'`. Try this:

```
UPDATE user SET
  surname='$sname', othername='$oname', sex='$sex',
  fee_receipt='$freceipt', j_regno='$j_regno', department='$department' 
WHERE id='$id'
```

It is good practice to use uppercase letters for SQL functions.

Also, your SQL can be easily injected. Use prepared statement and use `$_POST` instead `$_GET`. Here is an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) you can look at.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your query there shouldn't be any comma before where clause your updated query would be like this.

```
$rs = 'update user set
surname='$sname', othername='$oname', sex='$sex',
fee_receipt='$freceipt', j_regno='$j_regno', department='$department' WHERE id= '$id'"';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
 $id = $_GET['did'];
 $sname = $_GET['sname'];
 $oname = $_GET['oname'];
 $sex = $_GET['sex'];
 $freceipt = $_GET['freceipt'];
 $j_regno = $_GET['j_regno'];
 $department = $_GET['department'];
 $rs =  "update user set
surname='$sname', othername='$oname', sex='$sex',
fee_receipt='$freceipt', j_regno='$j_regno', department='$department', where `id`=`$id`";
$query =mysqli_query($cn,$rs) or die(mysqli_error($cn));
}
```

You have extra coma befor WHERE. And if you have some problem with mysql sintasix place

```
echo $rs;
```

befor calling mysqli_query and then check the response in any MySQL enviropment. It can be phpMyAdmin or some kind of free **heidisql**.

In your case u must protect your SQLQueryString or using prepare statement. Prepare statement the easiest way:

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
   if ( isset($_GET['did']) and
      isset($_GET['sname']) and
      isset($_GET['oname']) and
      isset($_GET['sex']) and
      isset($_GET['freceipt']) and
      isset($_GET['regno']) and
      isset($_GET['department']) ){

      $rs =  "update user set
      surname=?, othername=?, sex=?,
      fee_receipt=?, j_regno=?, department=?  where id=?";

      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($cn, $rs);
      if(!$stmt){
         echo mysqli_error ( $cn );
         // do somthing on error
      }

      if(!mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssssi', $sname, $oname,  $sex,$freceipt,$j_regno,$department,$id)){
           echo $stmt->error;
           // do somthing on error
      }

      $id = $_GET['did'];
      $sname = $_GET['sname'];
      $oname = $_GET['oname'];
      $sex = $_GET['sex'];
      $freceipt = $_GET['freceipt'];
      $j_regno = $_GET['j_regno'];
      $department = $_GET['department'];

      if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
          echo $stmt->error;
          // do somthing on error
      }

      if(!mysqli_stmt_close($stmt)){
         // not necessary :)
         echo mysqli_error ( $cn );
         // do somthing on error
      }

   }else{
      echo 'Bad input $_GET params';
      // do somthing on error
   }

}
```

This code can be smaller, but using "inline code" everyware can be hard for refactoring and finding floating errors in future.